# Ruby Module to create Class Variable with default value in included class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to create a ruby module that, when included by a class, sets up a class variable with a default value that can be overridden in the class definition. I've been twisting myself in knots with metaprogramming trying to get it to work but I just can't get it right.

What I Want:

```
class A
  include Nickname
end

A.nickname # => 'A'
A.new.nickname # => 'A'

class B
  include Nickname
  set_nickname "Bubba"
end

B.nickname # => 'Bubba'
B.new.nickname # => 'Bubba'

class BB < B
end

BB.nickname # => 'Bubba'
BB.new.nickname # => 'Bubba'
A.nickname # => 'A'
A.new.nickname # => 'A'
```

I tried

```
module Nickname

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval <<-EOS
      @@nickname = "#{klass.name}"
      def self.nickname
        @@nickname
      end
      def nickname
        @@nickname
      end
      def self.set_nickname(new_nick)
        @@nickname = new_nick
      end
    EOS
  end

end
```

but that set the nickname on the Nickname module, so every class that included the module would have the same Nickname (whatever was set last). **Turns out the code was right.** After 7stud pointed that out, I reviewed my work. It seems that because I was doing my testing in `irb` and had previously defined `Nickname` several other ways, I got the undesirable behavior. In fact, on a fresh load of `irb`, the above code works exactly like I want and expected. Sorry about that.

Then I tried using a class instance variable

```
module Nickname

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.send(:define_singleton_method, :nickname) do
      @nickname
    end
    klass.send(:define_method, :nickname) do
      klass.nickname
    end
    klass.send(:define_singleton_method, :set_nickname) do |new_nick|
      @nickname = new_nick
    end
    klass.set_nickname klass.name
  end

end
```

That almost worked, but it uses a Class Instance Variable, so `BB.nickname` is `nil`.

I've tried various combinations of `class_eval` and `instance_eval` inside `self.included` and I cannot get it all to work together. If I manage to get the value stored as a class variable in the including class, I can't get the class to be able to override the value and/or I cannot set a default value.

### EDIT

Moral 1 of the story, be careful about doing metaprogramming in `irb`. It's quite possible your failed experiments will ruin your next experiments.

Moral 2 of the story is that if you think class variables are strange, look at class instance variables with inheritance and `instance_variable_set/get`. When a subclass inherits the superclass' class instance variable, the variable is still attached to the superclass part of the subclass instance, so you cannot access it via `@var` in the subclass, and you can't access from a superclass function that accesses `@var`, but, as 7stud illustrates, you can access it from a superclass function that calls `instance_variable_get` on itself.

Comment: Using class variables has its quirk. If you were to change nickname for BB, then B would also have it changed. Not sure if desirable behaviour to you or not.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that a change by BB would affect B, and in my case that is desirable, but since SO is meant to inform everyone, I'm happy to see both solutions.

Comment: Re Moral2,  The pertinent rule is: An instance variable attaches to whatever object is self when the instance variable is created, and an instance variable is retrieved from whatever object is self when you try to access the instance variable.  If a subclass inherits a superclass method, and the subclass calls the inherited method, then inside the method self is equal to the subclass. In my `class instance` example, in order to make it work as you desired, I had to us the includer variable to get ahold of the instance variable because the implicit lookup on self wouldn't work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  If `BB` includes `Nickname`, it gets a fresh class variable and can have it's own value without affecting the superclass. @7stud's class instance variable solution has all the same problems as my class variable solution, but is harder (for me) to understand.

Comment: *When a subclass inherits the superclass' class instance variable*--That doesn't happen.  Class instance variables are not inherited.

Answer (score 2):

> ...but that set the nickname on the Nickname module...

I'm not seeing that:

```
module Nickname
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval %Q{
      @@nickname = #{name} 

      def self.set_nickname(new_nick)
        @@nickname = new_nick
      end
    }
  end

end

class A
  include Nickname
end

p Nickname.class_variables(false)
p A.class_variables(false)


A.set_nickname("Joe")

p Nickname.class_variables(false)
p A.class_variables(false)

--output:--
[]
[:@@nickname]
[]
[:@@nickname]
```

> every class
>   that included the module would have the same Nickname (whatever was
>   set last).

No, `include` isn't the culprit:

```
module Nickname
  def self.included(includer)
    includer.class_eval %Q{
      @@nickname = #{name}

      def self.set_nickname(new_nick)
        @@nickname = new_nick
      end

      def self.nickname
        @@nickname
      end
    }
  end

end

class A
  include Nickname
end

A.set_nickname("Joe")
p A.nickname

class B
  include Nickname
end

B.set_nickname("Sally")
p B.nickname
p A.nickname

--output:--
"Joe"
"Sally"
"Joe"
```

Rather, it's `inheritance` that's the problem:

```
module Nickname
  def self.included(includer)
    includer.class_eval %Q{
      @@nickname = #{name}

      def self.set_nickname(new_nick)
        @@nickname = new_nick
      end

      def self.nickname
        @@nickname
      end
    }
  end

end

class A
  include Nickname
end

A.set_nickname("Joe")
p A.nickname

class B < A
end

B.set_nickname("Sally")
p B.nickname
p A.nickname

--output:--
"Joe"
"Sally"
"Sally"
```

An `@@variable` is shared by all the classes in an inheritance hierarchy, which is what Sergio Tulentsev was trying to warn you about in the comments.  You probably don't want to use an `@@variable` (nobody does).  Here it is with a `class instance` variable, which doesn't suffer that problem:

```
module Nickname

  def self.included(includer)
    includer.class_eval do
      @nickname = includer.name  #Instance variables attach themselves to whatever object is self, and class_eval sets self to the receiver, i.e. includer

      define_method(:nickname) do  #Using define_method() with a block makes the includer variable visible inside the nickname() method.
        includer.instance_variable_get(:@nickname)
      end
    end

    includer.singleton_class.class_eval do
      define_method(:nickname) do
        includer.instance_variable_get(:@nickname)
      end
      define_method(:set_nickname) do |new_val|
        includer.instance_variable_set(:@nickname, new_val)
      end
    end

  end

end


class A
  include Nickname
end

p A.nickname
p A.new.nickname

class B
  include Nickname
  set_nickname "Bubba"
end

p B.nickname
p B.new.nickname

class BB < B
end

p BB.nickname
p BB.new.nickname

--output:--
"A"
"A"
"Bubba"
"Bubba"
"Bubba"
"Bubba"
```

Then you can set the class instance variable in BB, and it won't affect B's class instance variable:

```
...
...

class BB < B
  include Nickname
  set_nickname "Bubba Bubba"
end

p BB.nickname
p BB.new.nickname

p B.nickname
p B.new.nickname

--output:--
...
...
"Bubba Bubba"
"Bubba Bubba"
"Bubba"
"Bubba"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my initial attempt does, in fact, work. I've updated the question accordingly. Thank you to for showing how to make it work with class instance variables. The way you have to go about accessing the superclass instance variable from the subclass is a bit mind warping and something I've never seen explained anywhere before. You do still have to be careful in that a subclass can call `set_nickname` without (re-)including `Nickname`, and then just as with the class variables, it will change the value in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

[`Module#class_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_set) comes to the rescue:

```
▶ module A
▷   def self.included base
▷     base.class_variable_set :@@nickname, 'mudasobwa'
▷     class << base
▷       def nickname # extended class method
▷         class_variable_get :@@nickname
▷       end
▷     end
▷   end
▷ end

▶ class B
▷   include A
▷   def nickname # instance method, might be put in `A`
▷     @@nickname
▷   end
▷ end

▶ B.nickname
#⇒ "mudasobwa"
▶ B.new.nickname
#⇒ "mudasobwa"
▶ B.class_variable_set :@@nickname, 'google'
#⇒ "google"
▶ B.nickname
#⇒ "google"
▶ B.new.nickname
#⇒ "google"
```

Hope it helps.